# How to serialize object and append to xml as child?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm currently using the XmlSerializer class to serialize objects and store them.  However, the only way I can see to use the Serializer is to write the data out immediately to a stream.  What I want to do is have a single file that contains all of the serializations performed.

So is there any way to serialize an object to, say an XmlNode and then append that node to the root node of the xml file?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research, and it seems that your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473431/can-we-update-existing-xml-files-using-xmlserializer).

XMLSerializer does not support changing serialized data. What you can do is deserialize the file to get the data, update the data, and serialize the new data into a file that overwrites the old file. Try it out.

Comment: In fact, it's simpler than that. XML in a file, is _sequential_. You can't just insert stuff into the middle of a sequential file.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think to just include all of the objects in another object and serialize that.  Doh :)